# My nextjs docker-compose build fails to generate static pages. Can't get data from another hasura container while building.ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js, hasura

I have a nextjs app that is dependent on a hasura self hosted instance. both needs to be run as a docker container. I was able to make hasura up and running. when i build nextjs manually. it works. I am able to render data from hasure. when i try to build from a docker file or docer compose. it fails. I get the following error.

```sh
info  - Checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data...
info  - Generating static pages (0/14)
info  - Generating static pages (3/14)
info  - Generating static pages (6/14)
info  - Generating static pages (10/14)

Error occurred prerendering page "/post/new". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
FetchError: request to http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/1stkare/node_modules/.pnpm/node-fetch@2.6.1/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
info  - Generating static pages (14/14)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /post/new
    at /usr/src/app/1stkare/node_modules/.pnpm/next@11.0.2-canary.24_df9b789abc073be907b68727ab177fb5/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:473:19
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/usr/src/app/1stkare/node_modules/.pnpm/next@11.0.2-canary.24_df9b789abc073be907b68727ab177fb5/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
    at async /usr/src/app/1stkare/node_modules/.pnpm/next@11.0.2-canary.24_df9b789abc073be907b68727ab177fb5/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:752:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/usr/src/app/1stkare/node_modules/.pnpm/next@11.0.2-canary.24_df9b789abc073be907b68727ab177fb5/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
    at async /usr/src/app/1stkare/node_modules/.pnpm/next@11.0.2-canary.24_df9b789abc073be907b68727ab177fb5/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:630:13
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/usr/src/app/1stkare/node_modules/.pnpm/next@11.0.2-canary.24_df9b789abc073be907b68727ab177fb5/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
 ERROR  Command failed with exit code 1.
The command '/bin/sh -c pnpm build' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

my dockerfile-compose for hasura

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5555:5432
    expose:
      - "5555"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db-script:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      # POSTGRES_DB: 1stkare
      APP_DB_USER: postgres
      APP_DB_PASS: postgres
      APP_DB_NAME: 1stkare
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.0.3
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    expose:
      - "8080"
    restart: always
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/1stkare
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/1stkare
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: "true"
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: startup, http-log, webhook-log, websocket-log, query-log
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: myadminsecretkey
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET:wontsay
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_UNAUTHORIZED_ROLE: anonymous
      EVENT_WEBHOOK_SECRET: myeventwebhooksecret
      EVENT_WEBHOOK_URL_ON_USER_UPDATE: http://host.docker.internal:3000/api/events/on-user-update
  
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: dev_network
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  db_data:
```

my dockerfile for nextjs app

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/1stkare

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/1stkare
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
RUN curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.7.js | node - add --global pnpm

# Files required by pnpm install
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml /usr/src/app/1stkare/

# RUN npm i -g pnpm
RUN pnpm install

COPY . /usr/src/app/1stkare
RUN pnpm build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["pnpm", "start"]
```

my dockerfile-compose for nextjs app

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  1stkare-ui:
    build:
      context: ./
    environment:
      - EVENT_WEBHOOK_SECRET=myeventwebhooksecret
      - HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET=myadminsecretkey
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_HASURA_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql
      - SPACES_ENDPOINT=wontsay.wontsay.com
      - SPACES_BUCKET=wontsay.wontsay
      - SPACES_CDN_BASE_URL=https://wontsay.wontsay
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - '3000'
    container_name: 1stkare-ui
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/1stkare
      - /usr/src/app/1stkare/node_modules
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: dev_network
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `NEXT_PUBLIC_HASURA_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql` seems to be the issue I assume. When you are building your Next.js app inside Docker, it won't have access to `http://localhost:8080` which is outside of the docker network.

Try replacing that Hasura endpoint value to be `http://host.docker.internal:8080/v1/graphql`. (I assumed you are using macOS, since there was a previous usage of host.docker.internal in the event webhook url env of hasura docker-compose setup.

This way, Next.js docker build will be able to communicate with the network running outside docker sandbox.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was for a freelance project. I was finally able to do it by setting env variable for hosts as service container name.